# Windows 10 Focus Assist turns on when I press Winkey + D

Tags: windows-10, notifications, action-center

For some unknown reason, Focus Assist turns on when I hit 
<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
(keyboard shortcut for Show Desktop). To my knowledge, there is no keyboard shortcut for Focus Assist.

What is causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It appears the Desktop is a full screen app. The fix is to disable "When I'm using an app in full screen mode" under Automatic Rules.

[image]

More info: the issue is related with Nvidia GeForce Experience In-Game Overlay. See relevant thread [here](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/134768-focus-assistant-1903-a-3.html). I've tested with my machine and turning off In-Game does fix the issue.

Comment: I'm also seeing mysterious activation of Focus Assist, but I actually do want it to turn on when I'm playing a full-screen game.  Any other ideas?